# Access array in json file in python

Tags: python, arrays, json

Here is a question from an absolute beginner python developer.
Here is the challenge I have :)

not being able to access the "status" in this json file:

```
[{
        "id": 0,
        "sellerId": "HHH",
        "lat": 90.293846,
        "lon": 15.837098,
        "evses": [{
                "id": 0,
                "status": 1,
                "connectors": [{
                        "type": "Hyyyyp",
                        "maxKw": 22
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "id": 2001,
                "status": 2,
                "connectors": [{
                        "type": "Hyyyyp",
                        "maxKw": 22
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "id": 2002,
                "status": 1,
                "connectors": [{
                        "type": "Hyyyyp",
                        "maxKw": 22
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "id": 2003,
                "status": 1,
                "connectors": [{
                        "type": "Hyyyp",
                        "maxKw": 22
                    }
                ]
            }
        ] 

       }, {
            "id": 10001,
            "sellerId": 7705,
            "lat": 12.59962,
            "lon": 40.8767,
            "evses": [{
                    "id": 10001,
                    "status": 1,
                    "connectors": [{
                            "type": "Tyyyyp",
                            "maxKw": 22
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    "id": 10002,
                    "status": 2,
                    "connectors": [{
                            "type": "Tyyyyp",
                            "maxKw": 22
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    "id": 10003,
                    "status": 2,
                    "connectors": [{
                            "type": "Tyyyyp",
                            "maxKw": 22
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    "id": 10004,
                    "status": 2,
                    "connectors": [{
                            "type": "Tyyyyp",
                            "maxKw": 22
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, {
```

for the "id:10001" there are 3 cases which "status: 2".
So.. how do I print 3 for id:10001?

I guess I need to have an array for storying the ids itself and another array for storying the number of "status:2" for each id.

Here is my code:
firs I do print id:

```
with open('sample.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print(id['id'])
```

Then I think I need to access array evses:
So here is what I do:

```
print(data['evses'][0]['id']['status'])
```

But I get error on this line.

Comment: `data['evses'][0]` is a dictionary, `data['evses'][0]['id']` is 10001, it has no `'status'` key

Comment: Your example won't work because `status` is not a key of `id`.  
dataID = `data['evses'][0]['id']`
dataStatus = `data['evses'][0]['status']`

Comment: so how do I access the status? is not it through evses array?

Comment: Please show more of the data so we can show you how to get at those values

Comment: id 10001 has a status of 1. ids 10002, 10003 and 10004 have statuses of 2. So why would you want 3 for id 10001? Maybe you just want to know how many ids have a particular status value?

Comment: I need the number of "status which are equal to 2" for each id. I would like to plot them.
x axis as id numbers and y axis as number of status equal to 2

Comment: The number of statuses with a value of 2 in your sample data is 4 - i.e., 2001, 10002, 10003 and 10004

Comment: No I meant for each id. first id is equal 0 then the number of status: 2 for that is 1.
The next id is 10001 which has 3 status equal to 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following clarification from OP, this would be my proposed solution:

```
import json
from collections import Counter

def get_status_2_for_id(filename):
    count = Counter()
    with open(filename) as jdata:
        for e in json.load(jdata):
            if (id_ := e.get('id')) is not None:
                for f in e.get('evses', []):
                    if f.get('status') == 2:
                        count[id_] += 1
    return count.items()

for id_, count in get_status_2_for_id('sample.json'):
    print(f'id={id_} count={count}')
```

**Output:**

```
id=0 count=1
id=10001 count=3
```

Comment: It does not print out the output for me!

Comment: @user2758510 I created sample.json from the data you've shown and it works perfectly

Comment: are you sure that you got "output" using this code? It does not work for me!

Comment: If you're not getting any output then that's because your data doesn't match that shown in your question

Answer (score 1):

You can try this if its stored as a variable:

```
for status in json_data["evses"]:
    print('status = ', status['status'])
```

And this if it's stored in a file:

```
import json

status_pts = 1

with open('file.json') as json_file:
    data = json.loads(json_file.read())
    ls = data[0]['evses']
    for s in ls:
        if s['status'] == status_pts:
            print('id:', s['id'], "number of status =", status_pts)
```

Also, your json data wasn't closed off, the very last line has:

```
}, {
```

It needed:

```
}]
```

Comment: I get "TypeError" error in the for loop line

Comment: Is the data assigned to a variable? I put your json data into a variable called json_data.

Comment: The json file starts exactly with what I have in my question which is [{
is there anything missing you think?

Comment: Then how do I iterate through the ids and print out the number of status that are equal to 2 for each id? for example I would like to print out something like this: id = 0 , 1(number of status = 2) and  id:10001 , 3(number of status = 2)

Comment: I'm not real sure what you're after there.  I have tried understanding your new question and have edited my original. If my answer helped your original question, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: I will try to rephrase my question... We have two main ids in the file, right? One is id= 0 and the other one is id= 10001.

Comment: Eventhough there are some more ids in each one of these ids but I what I am interested in displaying is only the number of status=2 corresponding to each ids. So here for id=0 it will be 1 and for id= 10001 it will be 3.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you take a single JSON record of your data which is below

```
record = {
    "id": 10001,
    "sellerId": 7705,
    "lat": 12.59962,
    "lon": 40.8767,
    "evses": [{
        "id": 10001,
        "status": 1,
        "connectors": [{
            "type": "Tyyyyp",
            "maxKw": 22
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": 10002,
        "status": 2,
        "connectors": [{
            "type": "Tyyyyp",
            "maxKw": 22
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": 10003,
        "status": 2,
        "connectors": [{
            "type": "Tyyyyp",
            "maxKw": 22
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": 10004,
        "status": 2,
        "connectors": [{
            "type": "Tyyyyp",
            "maxKw": 22
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

From this data record above, if you want to count the number of occurences of a particular status you can do something like below

```
status_2_count = [stp["status"] for stp in record["evses"]].count(2)
```

We just generate a list of all statuses in the `record["evses"]` and count the occurence of a particualr status.

You can make this a function, and repeat it for other records in the file.

Comment: Tried it but did not work.
I got this error:
    status_2_count = [stp["status"] for stp in id["evses"]].count(2)
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable